# Is this MAC-then-encrypt scheme secure?

Tags: aes, symmetric, cmac

I have the following requirements:

- 64 bits (8 bytes) of data ($D$) that requires confidentiality and integrity;
- the data itself is a nonce, never need to authenticate/encrypt the same value twice (e.g. a counter);
- I can only use AES cipher (128-bits key);
- I can have a maximum of 128 bits as output (one block).

Given two different AES-128 keys ($K_\mathrm A$ for Authentication, $K_\mathrm E$ for Encryption), I'm using the following MAC-then-Encrypt scheme:

- compute $\mathit{MAC} = \operatorname{CMAC}(K_\mathrm A, D, 8)$ (see [RFC 4493](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493))
- truncate the MAC to get the tag: $T = \operatorname{MSB}_{64}(\mathit{MAC})$ (see [NIST 800-38B](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38b.pdf))
- get the plaintext $P = D\mathop\Vert T$ (16 bytes)
- get the ciphertext $C = \operatorname{AES}(K_\mathrm E, P)$ by using `AES/ECB/NoPadding` mode

I generally know that MAC-then-Encrypt schemes **can** be secure, but I'm not able to demonstrate it for this scheme. Could you elaborate on that? Is there any improvement I can do?

I know that a good alternative would be AES-GCM (or CCM). Is there any way to fit into a single block of ciphertext by using AES-GCM on 8 bytes of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of a *generic* security reduction for MAC-then-encrypt is basically only for pathological cases where an encryption scheme admits modifications to the ciphertext that don't affect the plaintext, like AES-CTR with an extra bit of key stream appended to the message on encryption and ignored on decryption.

So is your AES-CMAC-then-AES scheme or an AES-GCM variant secure?

**AES-CMAC-then-AES.**
What you described is a *deterministic nonceless authenticated encryption scheme*.  As such, it can't conceal repeated messages, but otherwise it provides confidentiality and authentication, as long as you reject invalid MAC tags before even thinking about the data.  Finding a way to reject replayed messages is your responsibility.

**AES-GCM.**
AES-GCM is a *deterministic nonce-based authenticated encryption scheme*.  That is, AES-GCM is a *different kind of cryptosystem* from AES-CMAC-then-AES.  *If* you can provide a 96-bit nonce for each message, *e.g.* a message sequence number, then it provides about the same security.*

AES-GCM is also quirky about nonce sizes: With a nonce size other than 96 bits, AES-GCM's security diminishes, because of the low but nonnegligible probability of collision in the internal 96-bit nonce derivation.  And, of course, with a repeated nonce, AES-GCM's security vanishes.

**But for the scenario you described, both more complex than you need!**

(CAVEAT LECTOR: This is not a peer-reviewed academic journal of cryptographic designs.  This is a pseudonymous stranger on the internet blathering crypto at you.)

You could use $C = \operatorname{AES}_k(D \mathbin\Vert 0^{64})$, and reject decryption if the message does not end with 64 zero bits.

For uniform random permutation $\pi\colon \{0,1\}^{128} \to \{0,1\}^{128}$, the adversary's chance of guessing a ciphertext $C'$ for which $\pi(C')$ has 64 trailing zero bits in one try is $2^{-64}$, which is the best you could hope for with an 8-byte authenticator anyway.

Obviously, $\operatorname{AES}_k^{-1}$ for uniform random $k \in \{0,1\}^{128}$ or $k \in \{0,1\}^{256}$ is not exactly a uniform random choice of permutation, but the attacker's advantage knowing $\pi = \operatorname{AES}_k^{-1}$ for some key $k$ is negligible: even in their worst case when $D$ is uniform, they have a far better chance of guessing $D$ or forging $C'$ than of guessing $k$.

---

<sub>* The short messages are critical here because the attacker's forgery probability is about $2^{-\tau}$ for CMAC but $\ell \cdot 2^{-\tau}$ for GCM, for $\tau$-bit tags and up to $128\ell$-bit messages, when the tag size $\tau$ is much smaller than the cipher block size 128.</sub>

<sub>Specifically, let $n$ be the block size in bits; $\tau$, the tag size in bits; $\ell$, the maximum message length in $n$-bit blocks; $q$, the number of oracle queries; and $f$, the number of forgery attempts.  Assume a uniform random permutation; $\operatorname{AES}_k$ is a good enough approximation.  For CMAC, the attacker's forgery probability is bounded by $$O(q \ell^2) 2^{-n} + 1 - \operatorname{Binom}(0; f, 2^{-\tau}) = O(q \ell^2) 2^{-n} + 1 - (1 - 2^{-\tau})^f,$$ which, for $f \lll 2^\tau$, is approximately $O(q \ell^2) 2^{-n} + f 2^{-\tau}$.  For GCM, the attacker's forgery probability is bounded by $$1 - \operatorname{Binom}(0; f, \ell 2^{-\tau}) = 1 - (1 - \ell 2^{-\tau})^f \approx f \ell 2^{-\tau}.$$</sub>

<sub>If $\tau$ is, say, 32, and you authenticate messages of up to 64 KB, CMAC limits the forger's success to about one in four *billion*, while GCM limits the forger's success to about one in four *thousand*.</sub>

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Yes, my application already rejects $D$ if it is old/replayed, so I need a nonceless scheme. I understand your point, I will consider your proposal of replacing the truncated MAC with a simpler string of 64 zeros (or maybe any other fixed string). Answer accepted, thank you.

Comment: TL;DR version: MAC then encrypt should be pad, MAC (including padding), then encrypt