# Authentication of data using XOR and a secure function

Tags: authentication, mac, authenticated-encryption

Suppose that:

- $i$ is a zero-based index.
- $K$ is a secret key.
- $X$ is a stream of data.
- $x_{i}$ denotes the $i$<sup>th</sup> block of data in $X$.
- $s$ is the number of blocks in $X$.
- $X = x_{0}\mathbin\|x_{1}\mathbin\|\dots\mathbin\|x_{s-2}\mathbin\|x_{s-1}$.
- $y_{i}$ is a value derived from $x_{i}$, $i$, and $K$ in a way that incorporates some known-to-be-secure function (like a block cipher).
- $\alpha = \bigoplus\limits_{i=0}^{s-1} y_{i}$.

If the authentication tag is derived from $\alpha$ and $K$ in some way that uses the same function used to in deriving $y_{i}$, then would this be a secure authentication algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

It can be.

Suppose $y_i = F_K(1 \mathbin\| i \mathbin\| x_i)$ and $t = \alpha \oplus F_K(0 \mathbin\| n)$ is the authentication tag, for some PRF $F_K$ and per-message nonce $n$.  The security of this structure is called XMACC and analyzed by [Bellare, Guérin, and Rogaway, ‘XOR MACs: New Methods for Message Authentication Using Finite Pseudorandom Functions’, Proceedings of CRYPTO '95, Springer LNCS 963, 1995](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/xormacs.pdf).

Suppose $y_i = x_i {K_0}^{i + 1}$ and $t = \alpha + K_1$ with arithmetic in $\operatorname{GF}(2^{128})$, where $K_0, K_1 \in \operatorname{GF}(2^{128})$ are uniform random, and $K_1$ is only ever used once.  This is the structure of GHASH, which is used by AES-GCM in Carter–Wegman mode with $K_0 = \operatorname{AES}_K(0)$ and $K_1 = \operatorname{AES}_K(n)$ for a per-message nonce $n$.

Comment: When I said "function" I didn't mean "pseudorandom function".

Comment: I don't understand.  You're saying that the functional relation $y_i = f(K, i, x_i)$ is not allowed to be built out of a pseudorandom function family $F_K$ with $f(K, i, x) = F_K(i \mathbin\| x)$?  Can you be more specific about the constraint you're imposing?

Comment: It can be. It could also be built on a pseudorandom permutation such as a block cipher (which I mentioned). I used the term "function" in its broader sense.

Comment: A PRP makes a reasonable approximation to a PRF.  If it didn't, we wouldn't use AES-CTR or AES-GCM.  If the parameter sizes all fit, you could certainly use $F_K(b) = \operatorname{AES}_K(b)$.

Comment: What is the upper bound on the security of this scheme?

Comment: They're both bounded by the smaller of the key size and the tag size.  The detailed forgery probability for XMACC is analyzed in the paper in Sec. 5.2 on p. 11, in the information-theoretic setting (meaning adversary assumes $F$ is chosen uniformly at random from all functions) and in the computational setting (meaning adversary assumes use of $F_K$ where $K$ is chosen uniformly at random from 128- or 256-bit keys).  The detailed forgery probability for GHASH is the standard for polynomial evaluation MACs, with no computational conditions.

Comment: Is the general style of XOR MACs patented?

Comment: That, I'm afraid, is a question for your patent attorney, not for a bone-eating vulture, difficult as the two may be to tell apart sometimes.

Comment: So, the upper security bound would be $min(2^k, 2^t)$?

Comment: Roughly yes, with some [caveats](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51416/49826) about short messages and small or truncated tags.  I leave it as an exercise for the reader to study the forgery probabilities in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of what [this Bernstein paper](https://cr.yp.to/papers/stretch.pdf) calls an (unprotected) **counter sum**.  It is not a secure MAC, it is vulnerable to a simple attack (and I'll use 1-based indexing, unlike your question's 0-based indexes):

1. Adversary chooses a one-block message $x$ and queries for its tag; gets back $t_1 = f(1, x)$.
2. Adversary chooses a one-block message $x'$ (distinct from $x$) and queries for its tag; gets back $t_2 = f(1, x')$.
3. Adversary computes the *difference* of the two tags: $d = t_1 \oplus t_2$.
4. Adversary chooses a block $y$ and queries for the tag of $x \mathbin\Vert y$; gets back $t_3 = f(1, x) \oplus f(2, y)$.
5. Adversary guesses that the tag of $x' \mathbin\Vert y$ is $t_4 = t_3 \oplus d$.

The reasoning is that the difference between the tags of $x$ and $x'$ has got to be the same as that between the tags of $x \mathbin\Vert y$ and $x' \mathbin\Vert y$:

$$
\begin{align}
d &= t_1 \oplus t_2 \\
d &= f(1, x) \oplus f(1, x') \\
d \oplus t_3 &= f(1, x) \oplus f(1, x') \oplus t_3 \\
d \oplus t_3 &= f(1, x) \oplus f(1, x') \oplus f(1, x) \oplus f(2, y) \\
d \oplus t_3 &= f(1, x') \oplus f(2, y) \\
d \oplus t_3 &= t_4
\end{align}
$$

A simple solution is to compute a **protected counter sum**, like Bernstein's paper describes:

$$
f'(x_1, \dots, x_n) = f(0, f(1, x_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus f(n, x_n))
$$

The outer, zero-indexed application of $f$ "protects" the output of the XOR from the attack above.

---

**EDIT:** @Melab has highlighted that I seem to have misinterpreted the last sentence in the question:

> If the authentication tag is derived from $\alpha$ and $K$ in some way that uses the same function used to in deriving $y_{i}$, then would this be a secure authentication algorithm?

The problem here is when you say "some way," because it's not clear whether you mean to ask whether there exists some way that will yield a secure MAC, or whether your construction is secure given *any way* of using the same function.  The answer is "yes" for the former, "no" for the latter.

Comment: I think my calculation of the authentication tag already does that.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that last sentence then.  I'll make an edit.

Comment: Are we looking at a security equal to the key size?